# Magento return a list of categories from a collection

Tags: php, magento, collections, product

I have edited the question to hopefully make more sense...

Our store has categories for product types for example "headlights" "fog lights" etc.

I have created new categories for each vehicle make and model, for example "Audi" > "Audi A3". From these subcategories I will load a collection of products that belong to that specific make and model so make="audi" model ="a3".

The following code loads the collection of products for each make and model.

```
<?php
// get current category name
$_catname = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
// Instantiate a category collection object
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
// Select which fields to load into the category
// select fields to load
$_products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$_products->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$_products->addAttributeToSelect('model');
$_products->addAttributeToSelect('small_image');
$_products->addAttributeToFilter('model',$_catname);

// Load the collection
$_products->load();

foreach($_products as $product){
echo 'Name:'.$product->name.' sku:'.$product->sku.' Model:'.$product-    >model.;
}

?>
```

This prints a list of all products from our store that have the model which is equal to the category name. So for Audi A3, it returns a list of products with model="a3"

From this collection I would like to get a list of the categories that each product loaded through the collection belongs to.

The products therefore may exist in different categories. Example, collection shows all products relating to "Audi A3". This may include a headlight, a fog light and a tail light. All 3 products exist in their individual categories, but are being loaded into a collection for a new category "Audi A3".

I would like to get a list of categories that these products exist in.

Maybe this isn't possible as the collection is being loaded in a new category, this is what I am unsure of.

Comment: Hello Frank can u please explain what type result you want to have from the collection of product ? Cause i am not able to get your question ?

Comment: I would like a list of the categories that the products within the collection belong to. For example, the collections will return products for an "audi a3". This collection contains headlights, tail lights etc. which all reside within their own category. I would like a list of the categories that exist from the returned collection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop throught the collection and do something like :

```
$categories = array();
foreach ($_products as $_product){
   $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
   foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId){
       $categories[]=$categoryId;
   }
}
$categoriesIds = array_unique($categories);
```

I did not test but I believe that it works without or with a few modification.

Comment: again this just returns the value "array". Strange?

Comment: if you use flat catalog and you have added products without reindexing, it can happen. you can check as well that the category is set for the product and the store you run that on. if you import your products throught a script, it can be that they are only affected to admin store... and many other caveats :) feel free to comment or to edit your original post with more information.

Comment: I have edited my original post. Hopefully explains my problem a little better.

Comment: I am not sure I really understand your problem or the return value of such a function. If you do var_dump($categoriesIds); at the end it returns an empty array ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well.

**For the Getting the product of Specific Catagory**

```
$categoryIds = array(2,4);//category id

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
```

**Get Product for Specific product Id**

```
$productids = array(52,62);//product ids
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array( 'in' => $productids));
```

Hope this will Make your Day !!

Cheers !!! :P :)